# Treat escape key as an action instead of a character in Python input

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a **command-line** application, I'm using the following code (from [Andreas Renberg](https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/6570952)) to ask the user a yes/no question (it just uses the standard `input`):

```
# Taken from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577058-query-yesno/
#  with some personal modifications
def yes_no(question, default=True):
    valid = {"yes":True, "y":True, "ye":True,
             "no":False, "n":False }
    if default == None:
        prompt = " [y/n] "
    elif default == True:
        prompt = " [Y/n] "
    elif default == False:
        prompt = " [y/N] "
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid default answer: '%s'" % default)
 
    while True:
        sys.stdout.write(question + prompt)
        choice = input().lower()
        if default is not None and choice == '':
            return default
        elif choice in valid.keys():
            return valid[choice]
        else:
            sys.stdout.write("Please respond with 'yes' or 'no' "\
                             "(or 'y' or 'n').\n")
```

If the user types `"yes"` (or an equivalent) the function returns `True`, and `"no"` returns `False`. If they just press <kbd>↵ Return</kbd>, the `default` value is chosen.

However, if the user presses <kbd>Esc</kbd>, it gets treated as a character. Is there instead a way to cause the function to return `False` if that key is pressed? The few results I have found in my own searches seem overly complicated or only work on some operating systems.

Comment: `it gets treated as a character` - that's not really true, it depends on which underlying library is used. On my system (linux, which uses readline if available), pressing `Esc` at an `input()` promt doesn't do anything.

Comment: If you're on windows then [msvcrt](http://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html) module may help.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I'm in Ubuntu, and since this code is for an open-source tool, the code needs to work reliably across platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch an <kbd>Esc</kbd> press you have to implement something like `getch` method which will get you one character at a time.

Here is a simplistic implementation that works.

```
if platform_is_windows:
    from msvcrt import getch

elif platform_is_posix:
    import sys
    import tty
    import termios

    def getch():
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
        return ch
```

Then you just have a `while` loop with `getch` until you get an <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>↵ Return</kbd>.

*Note: I haven't specified a way to determine the platform since there are multiple ways to do that, and there are a lot answers on SO on that topic.*

Comment: For windows there is `getch()` in the python standard module [msvcrt](http://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html).

Comment: @TobiMarg Thanks for the hint. Fixed. It's a really old peace of code and I have no idea why I used that instead of `msvcrt` module.

Comment: This will not work because hitting any special key that starts with `\x1b` will fire this...